Authorship Order for a Master's Thesis-Based Paper
I am working on a research paper based on my master's thesis, where my supervisor provided the initial idea. However, I conducted all the coding, data analysis, trained the models, and wrote the thesis.  Me and my supervisor are from different universities, and his university will fund the journal publication based on my work. Given this situation, I am uncertain about the appropriate authorship order. Should my supervisor or I be the first author in this case? My supervisor wants to be the first author. Is this a common practice?

This question is similar to: Should I agree to my supervisor's request to place him as first author of my paper?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Does this person still have a supervisory position over you? Do you need them for future letters of recommendation?

@Sursula, the issues in that other paper seem different than this one. Perhaps they need separate answers.

This depends on the field. In my field the supervisor would be the last and corresponding author, you would be the first author. There are other fields where the rules are different, for example the order could be always alphabetical.

This answer is a bit hypothetical, since I don't know if you still have a supervisor-student relationship.
Also note that my views aren't universal, and I'm pretty intolerant of what I see as abuse of students. In my view, however, you are the first author and, in some fields like CS (which I think you are in) you would be the sole author. Having given you the idea for the project doesn't make them an author at all, though funding your project and providing the means to carry it out might well be. But, ideas, such as the idea for the project, are free and not "owned" by anyone. Had the advisor wanted to be first author they could have done the work themself.
However, there are considerations beyond fairness and justice that must, sadly, be taken in to account. It normally does a student no good in their studies or their career to fight with a supervisor. Sometimes you just have to be stepped on a bit in the short term to maximize your options in the long term. And, one paper won't make or break your career, even if you are denied a (IMO) proper place in author order.
I often give this advice here, and hate to have to write it. But the world ain't perfect. Think long term.
